# How to get the BUILD_USER in Jenkins when a human rebuilds a job triggered by timer?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

EDIT: I use this plugin to schedule runs btw: https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/

I have set slack notification which would automatically be sent when the timer(scheduler) starts the execution.

In the slack channel, it would post something like this when the auto-build starts:

```
(/ci/master-15): Started by timer with parameters: {URL=https://shop.com, USERNAME=yyy, PASSWORD=xxs, SLACK-NOTIFY-CHANNEL=#JENKINS-REPORTS}
```

And when the run is complete, a message similar to this would be posted to the channel:

```
(/ci/master-15): The job is now complete. Here are the execution summary
```

Groovy:

```
BUILD_TRIGGERED_BY = currentBuild.getBuildCauses().shortDescription[0]
SEND_SLACK_NOTIF(BUILD_TRIGGER_BY)
```

Now, If a human rebuilds one of these timer jobs after they're unsuccessful, I would expect it to say "Started by andrea-hyong@gmail.com" but instead

In the pipeline status it shows:

```
Started by timer with parameters: {URL=https://shop.com, USERNAME=yyy, PASSWORD=xxs, SLACK-NOTIFY-CHANNEL=#JENKINS-REPORTS}

Started by user andrea-hyong@gmail.com

Rebuilds build #14
```

In the slack message it shows:

```
Started by timer with parameters: {URL=https://shop.com, USERNAME=yyy, PASSWORD=xxs, SLACK-NOTIFY-CHANNEL=#JENKINS-REPORTS}
```

How can I make it send the username instead of timer?

Comment: What do you have in `SEND_SLACK_NOTIF` function?

Comment: slackSend(channelName, BUILD_TRIGGERED_BY) - takes two parameter channel name and a message.

Comment: Do you always see this behavior when triggered manually?

Comment: Yes. When I rebuild a run that was triggered by timer, I'd expect it to add me as the primary user

Comment: How are you rerunning a completed build which was triggered by the timer?

Comment: Like this: https://plugins.jenkins.io/rebuild/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is a result of the plugins you are using. I assume the `rebuild` plugin picks both triggers when rebuilding the Job. Since you have consistent behavior when rebuilding, you can improve your Groovy code to something like the one below.

```
BUILD_TRIGGERED_BY = currentBuild.getBuildCauses().shortDescription.size() > 1 ?  currentBuild.getBuildCauses().shortDescription[1] : currentBuild.getBuildCauses().shortDescription[0]
```